# I got or I was fascinated

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, verbs

The sentence I want to write is:

> **I was fascinated** by the role that science and engineering plays in high-technology companies.

I think that this sentence convey the idea that in the past I was fascinated but no longer. I would like to express that once I got fascinated, the fascination didn't end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that you "became fascinated", or that your "fascination began". To further strengthen the idea that the fascination was permanent you could add the word "first" and say that you "first became fascinated" or that your "fascination first began".